# How to search on enter on perticular Column in datatable using yadcf

Tags: filter, datatable, yadcf

I am using yadcf plugin for datatable and it works great but the problem is I have 7 columns and 2 have dropdown filters and 4 have input search filter but now I want to modify the search behavior for only one column from 4 so it can only search when user press enter after entering in the search box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible with yadcf alone, you might add your own tweaks, but IMO, the behavior you described is very not intuitive for the end-user / from a UX perspective